# What is the life-span of the various organs in the human body?

Tags: organs

It is possible for a person to donate the harvestable organs (kidneys, eyes, and such) posthumously. Let's assume for a moment that the technology exists to kill rejection, and maintain the organ in excellent shape after it is harvested.

Could the organ/s ( e.g. Eye ) (assuming a decent life-style) travel for centuries from one donor to yet another donee? What is the typical life-span of the various organs in the human body assuming a healthy, and low stress life?

p.s. It's a curiosity question; my eyes even millenia after my death would continue to see.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can infer relative lifespan from the age at which organs start declining in someone of average health.

Skin, muscles, bones, eyes, and ears start to visibly decline around age 40.

Kidneys become smaller and their ability to filter blood starts to decline around age 30.

Brain function begins to decline around 70, even in the absence of neurodegenerative diseases such as Alzheimers.

I don't think any organs can be passed through people for centuries, since decline of virtually every organ is observed even in individuals in perfect health. There may be two exceptions: The digestive tract and liver seem to be the most long-lived and are very little affected in healthy elders, probably because they regenerate their cells.

[Reference](http://www.merckmanuals.com/home/older_peoples_health_issues/the_aging_body/changes_in_the_body_with_aging.html)